# Mensaje con temporizador

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy intentando mostrar un mensaje al eliminar un registro y que al pasar 2 segundos desaparezca y me redireccione a otra página.

Tengo el siguiente código. Me despliega el mensaje pero no desaparece y visualmente no es muy agradable.

Comparto el codigo completo de la hoja en donde deberia ir el mensaje al eliminar el registro, en la parte inferior agregue el codigo enviado.

```
       <?php 
session_start();
if($_SESSION['rol'] != 1)
{
    header("location: ./");
}
include "../conexion.php";

if(!empty($_POST))
{
    if($_POST['idusuario'] == 1){
        header("location: lista_usuarios.php");
        mysqli_close($conection);
        exit;
    }
    $idusuario = $_POST['idusuario'];

    $query_delete = mysqli_query($conection,"UPDATE usuario SET estatus = 0 WHERE idusuario = $idusuario ");
    mysqli_close($conection);
}

if(empty($_REQUEST['id']) || $_REQUEST['id'] == 0 )
{
    header("location: lista_usuarios.php");
    mysqli_close($conection);
}
else
{
    $idusuario = $_REQUEST['id'];

    $query = mysqli_query($conection,"SELECT u.nombre,u.usuario,r.rol FROM usuario u INNER JOIN rol r ON u.rol = r.idrol
                                      WHERE u.idusuario = $idusuario ");
    
    mysqli_close($conection);
    $result = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    if($result > 0)
    {
        while ($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) 
        {
            $nombre = $data['nombre'];
            $usuario = $data['usuario'];
            $rol     = $data['rol'];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        header("location: lista_usuarios.php");
    }
}

  ?>

  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<?php include "includes/scripts.php"; ?>
<title>Eliminar Usuario</title>
  </head>
   <body>

<?php include "includes/header.php"; ?>
<section id="container">
<br>
    <div class="data_delete">
    <br>
        <h2><i class="fas fa-user-times"></i> ¿Está seguro de eliminar el siguiente registro?</h2>
        <br>
        
        <p>Nombre: <span><?php echo $nombre; ?></span></p>
        <p>usuario: <span><?php echo $usuario; ?></span></p>
        <p>Tipo Usuario: <span><?php echo $rol; ?></span></p>
        

        <form method="post" action="">
            <input type="hidden" name="idusuario" value="<?php echo $idusuario; ?>">
            <a href="lista_usuarios.php" class="btn_cancel">Cancelar</a>
            <div id="mensaje-emergente"></div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn_ok" onclick="ejecutaAlerta()"><i class="fas fa-user-times"></i> Eliminar</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
<?php include "includes/footer.php"; ?>

   <script>
   function ejecutaAlerta()
   {
/* Localizamos el contenedor y cambiamos el texto */
let mensaje = document.getElementById('mensaje-emergente');
mensaje.innerText = 'Hola StackOverflow!';
/* Hacemos aparecer el mensaje */
mensaje.style.visibility = 'visible';
mensaje.style.opacity = 1;
setTimeout(function() 
{
    /* Hacemos desaparecer el mensaje suavemente */
    mensaje.style.opacity = 0;
    /* Tras los 0.5 segundos de la animación cargamos la web de destino */
    setTimeout(function() 
    {
        mensaje.style.visibility = 'hidden';
        window.location = lista_usuarios.php;
    }, 500);
}, 5000);
    }
   </script>
   </body>
   </html>
```

Comment: En realidad un mensaje que indique que el registro se elimino y después de unos segundos redireccione a otra pagina

Comment: Mostrar el mensaje con una popup tal vez no sea la mejor forma hablando visualmente, puedes implementar algo como bootstrap ya usando la funcion de dismiss [Revisa este fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/itdancruz/q3ykdwhg/3/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te recomiendo mostrar ese mensaje emergente dentro de la propia página. Todo quedará más sencillo y visualmente más atractivo.

**Edición (tras conocer el código completo)**

He usado [`Event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) para evitar que el botón cumpla su cometido (enviar el formulario) cuando lo pulsamos, pero lo hacemos al finalizar la animación con [`HTMLFormElement.submit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit):

```js
function ejecutaAlerta(evento) {
  /* Evitamos la ejecución del comportamiento habitual del botón */
  evento.preventDefault();
  /* Localizamos el contenedor y cambiamos el texto */
  let mensaje = document.getElementById('mensaje-emergente');
  mensaje.innerText = 'Hola StackOverflow!';
  /* Hacemos aparecer el mensaje */
  mensaje.style.visibility = 'visible';
  mensaje.style.opacity = 1;
  /* Esperamos 3 segundos (3000 milisegundos) antes de ocultar el mensaje */
  setTimeout(function() {
    /* Hacemos desaparecer el mensaje suavemente */
    mensaje.style.opacity = 0;
    /* Tras 0.5 segundos (500 ms) de la animación cargamos la web de destino */
    setTimeout(function() {
      mensaje.style.visibility = 'hidden';
      window.location = 'https://about.gitlab.com/';
      /* Realizamos el envío real del formulario */
      evento.target.parentNode.submit();
    }, 500);
  }, 3000);
}
```

```css
#mensaje-emergente {
  /* Posicionaremos el mensaje en el centro de la ventana */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%; left: 50%;
  /* Configuramos ancho y alto deseado */
  width: 150px; height: 100px;
  /* Ahora debemos desplazar la mitad del ancho y alto */
  margin-left: -75px; margin-top: -50px;
  /* Inicialmente debe estar oculto */
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  /* Animamos la salida de la invisibilidad y opacidad */
  transition: visibility 0s, opacity 0.5s linear;
  /* Configuramos el aspecto del mensaje */
  border-radius: 8px;
  border: 4px solid #73AD21;
  background-color: rgba(127, 192, 0, 0.5);
  padding: 5px 10px;
  /* Centramos el texto del contenido */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<form method="post" action="https://httpbin.org/post">
<input type="hidden" name="idusuario" value="1111" />
<button type="submit" class="btn_ok" onclick="ejecutaAlerta(event)">⌧ Eliminar</button>
</form>

<div id="mensaje-emergente"></div>
```

---

Por último, decirte que esta no es la manera más elegante de hacerlo. Lo mejor, visualmente hablando, sería hacerlo a través de XHR y que la fila de la tabla desaparezca sin que la página tenga que recargarse.

Además, tu código PHP sufre los [graves problemas de seguridad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY) asociados a la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL).

Una solución rápida podría ser usando [`mysqli_real_escape_string()`](https://www.php.net/mysqli.real-escape-string) de la siguiente manera:

```
/* Escapamos el contenido de $idusuario para evitar inyección SQL */
$idusuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conection, $_POST['idusuario']);
$query_delete = mysqli_query($conection, "
    UPDATE usuario
    SET estatus = 0
    WHERE idusuario = '$idusuario'
");
```

Y más tarde:

```
$idusuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conection, $_REQUEST['idusuario']);
$query = mysqli_query($conection, "
    SELECT
        u.nombre,
        u.usuario,
        r.rol
    FROM usuario u
    INNER JOIN rol r ON u.rol = r.idrol
    WHERE u.idusuario = '$idusuario'
");
```

Comment: Cargue el codigo y alcanzo a ver el mensaje, pero muy poco tiempo, intente ajustando los valores, pero no logro que permanezca por mas tiempo.

Comment: Cambia la línea final que pone `}, 2000);`. El parámetro son milisegundos, así que 2000 indica dos segundos, si lo cambias por 5000 se mostrará durante 5 segundos.

Comment: Hice los cambios, pero el mensaje no se visualiza ni un segundo, aparace y enseguida se borra, he intentado varias formas pero no logro que se mantenga mas tiempo, tu sabes alguna forma de validar que no sea mi codigo el que tiene algun problema??? gracias

Comment: ¿Puedes compartir el código completo de tu página o darme la URL para visitarla? Si quieres modifico mi ejemplo para que compruebes que, efectivamente, si cambio `2000` por `5000` el mensaje emergente estará más tiempo en pantalla.

Comment: Edite la consulta, ahí esta el código de la hoja donde debería ir el mensaje, tu codigo lo agregue al final.

Comment: Vale, ahora ya está mucho más claro lo que te pasa. No puedes poner todo este código en un botón de envío de formulario porque ese botón realizará el envío inmediato de los datos del mismo, impidiendo que puedas ver los efectos. Tienes dos soluciones para este problema: 1.- mostrar el mensaje *ANTES* de realizar el envío del formulario, 2.- realizar el envío del formulario a través de XHR (ajax) *ANTES* de que se muestre el mensaje y mostrar el mensaje solo si el borrado fue exitoso o un mensaje de error en caso contrario.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, me queda mas claro el problema, lo de ajax creo que seria la mejor opción pero desconozco como hacerlo,  pero creo que es mas fácil para mi la primera opción, tu me podrías indicar porfa como lo hago para mostrar el mensaje antes de enviar los datos, gracias

Comment: No es la manera más elegante de hacerlo, pero espero que te sea de ayuda la edición que he hecho para solucionar tu problema.

Comment: He agregado una nota final a mi respuesta para mitigar los [graves problemas de seguridad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY) que tiene tu código PHP relacionados con la [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyección_SQL).

Comment: Agradezo tu ayuda, el mensaje se muestra bien y luego vuelvo a la pagina de origen, pero el registro no se elimina.

Comment: En tu comentario mencionas HTMLFormElement.submit() pero no lo veo en el codigo, sera ese el problema??

Comment: ¿Sin este código el mensaje se elimina correctamente? En cuanto a `HTMLFormElement`, es el nombre de la clase, la etiqueta `<form>` genera una instancia de esa clase en el DOM..

Comment: Efectivamente sin el código elimina bien el registro.

Comment: Buenas tardes Jeison. ¿Sería posible ver el código completo para revisarlo? Gracias

Comment: si, no hay problema, intentare compartirlo

Answer (score 1):

Comentarios:

- En lugar de `window.open` yo te sugiero el uso de [`window.location.replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/replace) dentro de la cual indicaremos la ruta a la que deseamos llegar pero dentro de la misma pestaña
- No veo para que usar `document.write`cuando la intención solo es mostrar un texto tal vez en una sección específica de la página (*sería mas funcional hacerlo así*).

  - En este caso sería mas simple obtener una etiqueta HTML por su id
  - Añadir el mensaje/texto a dicha etiqueta HTML
- Tampoco veo el caso del método [`focus()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/focus) es decir si la intención es mostrar un aviso y luego redirigir entonces esta demás buscar darle foco a algún elemento de la página web

Código:

```
<button id="eliminado">Eliminar</button>
<span id="aviso"></span>
<script>
  let botonEliminar = document.getElementById('eliminado');
  let aviso = document.getElementById('aviso');
  
  botonEliminar.addEventListener('click', () => {
    aviso.innerText = 'Registro eliminado';
    
    setTimeout(() => {
      window.location.replace('ruta_de_tu_siguiente_destino');
    }, 2000);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Obviamente los tres puntos realizan una función: abren una ventana emergente (o pestaña nueva), carga contenido en ella con `w.write()` y fuerza que se muestre con `focus()` (por si el navegador está configurado para abrir nuevas pestañas en segundo plano). Esto no se puede reemplazar directamente por el `replace()` sin reimplementar todo el proceso. Está claro que eso "queda feo" y está solicitando ayuda para mejorarlo. Te llevas mi +1 por implementar la misma solución que yo.

Comment: hola @OscarGarcia te agradezco los comentarios, la tenía para publicar desde ayer que vi la pregunta pero hubo una duda (*que de hecho eliminé*) por que el OP ya no me la respondió y tomé el riesgo de responder, caigo en cuenta que en este caso es mejor que la respuesta que perduré sea la tuya, hice la propuesta revisando algo que aportarle pero al final tus comentarios son muy ciertos. Saludos

Comment: En la variedad está el gusto. Quien visite esta pregunta en el futuro tendrá varias maneras de resolver el problema. La tuya me gusta más porque has usado `addEventListener` en lugar del atributo `onclick`, y que has usado la versión corta de la función en vez de la definición más conocida. Yo he evitado hacer esos cambios tan drásticos para facilitar la compresión por parte del OP.

Comment: @OscarGarcia muy cierto, sin embargo tu comentario fue muy *nutritivo* al respecto de ciertas partes del código del OP que di por centadas y debí explicarle de forma mas clara